# Assembly, How to fix Error: operand type mismatch for `and'

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86-64, cpu-registers, att

In assembly I wrote:

and $0x8000000000000000, %rax

what why I am getting errors? rax register is 64 bit and so is my imm.

> merged.asm:8: Error: operand type mismatch for `and'

Comment: this isn't a duplicate, it's and not add

Comment: AND and ADD are different instructions of course, but they're extremely similar in their encoding options and resulting limitations: there is no form with a 64bit immediate operand. The basic work-arounds are also the same, you may use some other alternatives depending on what you need this operation for.

Comment: When in doubt consult an instruction set reference. You will not find an `AND` that takes a full 64 bit immediate.

Comment: I updated @harold's linked answer to be even clearer that it's not just `add`, it's every instruction except `mov`.  Of course if you'd actually checked to see if `and` had the same limitations, you would have found for your that it did.  When x86-64 experts on Stack Overflow try to help you, it's usually a good idea to consider the possibility that they might be right.